# Check how many times decimal occurred in the number?

Tags: javascript

var abc = 134.67.3.56;

There are 3 decimal present in the variable abc.

How to get this via javascript? As new to coding if anyone could suggest then it would be really helpful! Will it be possible without converting it into string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually, your assumed number is not a number. a number can only have one decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split('.')` to get the elements splitted with `.` and then get the length of the array.

```js
var abc = "134.67.3.56";
var count = abc.split('.').length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: can't we do without converting it into string?

Comment: That must be a string as `134.67.3.56` is not a valid integer in javascript @PoojaThapa